# Why is my loop mixing the first loop and final loops first input

Tags: c#, winforms, for-loop

Basically, I have 4 arrays with values I input into my UI.
I'm trying to write my arrays to a binary file using a for loop and the arrays can hold 10 elements, the first loop always has an element of the final loop and vice versa:

[image]

The loops are separated by -+- and the first should be all "a" and the final should be all "c".
What am I doing wrong here?

This is my main:

```
private void saveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        //quick if to make sure that there's actually some substance in the input fields
    if (titleBox.Text == String.Empty || platformBox.Text == String.Empty ||
        genreBox.Text == String.Empty || publisherBox.Text == String.Empty)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error:\n\nPlease Input something into each the fields required","Wow, the audacity of this user");
    }
    else
    {
        game.Title = titleBox.Text;
        game.Platform = platformBox.Text;
        game.Genre = genreBox.Text;
        game.Publisher = publisherBox.Text;

        //Try catch implemented to stop and alert the user that the arrays have hit capacity
        try
        {
            //continued appending of the 1D arrays
            for (arrEnd = 0; arrEnd < 1; arrEnd++)
            {
                titleArray[arrIterator] = game.Title;
                platformArray[arrIterator] = game.Platform;
                genreArray[arrIterator] = game.Genre;
                publisherArray[arrIterator] = game.Publisher;
            }
            if (firstEntry == true)
            {
                displayBox.Items.Add("-------------");
                firstEntry = false;
            }
            //taking what had been stowed in the arrays and placing it in the listbox
            displayBox.Items.Add(titleArray[arrIterator]);
            displayBox.Items.Add(platformArray[arrIterator]);
            displayBox.Items.Add(genreArray[arrIterator]);
            displayBox.Items.Add(publisherArray[arrIterator]);
            displayBox.Items.Add("-------------");
            titleBox.Focus();
            bubbleSort(titleArray);

            //creating a duplicate Title array to be sorted
            sortedTitleArray = titleArray;

            //Attempting to generate a data file with the info inside
            try
            {
                //the creating and subsequent writing of the binary file
                string fileName = "Books";
                StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fileName);

                for (arrData = 0; arrData < titleArrayL; arrData++ )
                {
                    sw.WriteLine("-+-");
                    sw.WriteLine(titleArray[arrData]);
                    sw.WriteLine(platformArray[arrData]);
                    sw.WriteLine(genreArray[arrData]);
                    sw.WriteLine(publisherArray[arrData]);
                    sw.WriteLine("-+-");
                }
                sw.WriteLine("------------------");

                for (arrData = 0; arrData < titleArrayL; arrData++)
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(sortedTitleArray[arrData]);
                }
                titleArrayL++;
                sw.Close();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
                MessageBox.Show("Didn't work out, sorry Homie\nReason Being, none of the available or predetermined paths for the data file were available");
            }
            //Using the Bubble sort method to sort the Title array
            bubbleSort(sortedTitleArray);
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Arrays have hit capacity and can hold no more values","Sorry dawg");
            saveButton.Enabled = false;
        }

        /*stopping the program from adding more to the arrays than they can specifically handle, disabled due to try catch above, might reactivate though since cleaner
          if(arrIterator == 9)
        {
              saveButton.Enabled = false;
        }
        */
        arrEnd = 0;
        arrIterator++;
        dumpeet();
    }
}
```

Also uses a custom made `Bubble Sort`:

```
void bubbleSort(string[] sorter)
{
    string temp;
    for (int write = 0; write < sorter.Length; write++)
    {
        for (int index = 0; index < (sorter.Length - 1); index++)
        {
            if (string.Compare(sorter[index], sorter[index + 1]) < 0) //compares the two numbers and swaps if less than
            {
                //swap
                temp = sorter[index];
                sorter[index] = sorter[index + 1];
                sorter[index + 1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you breakpoint and check the values in your loop? Maybe the problem is in the content of your arrays and not the loops themselves.

Comment: lets see your bubblesort method

Comment: i believe its the way youre sorting your `titles` as they are the ones mixed around. please post  bubblesort

Comment: sorry forgot to add the Bubblesort and have now

Comment: This line:  `sortedTitleArray = titleArray;` does not create a duplicate array as your comment indicates.  It creates another reference to the _same_ array!

Comment: Thank you Chris, it was the source of almost all my problems ahaha, thank you for the insight!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 //compares the two numbers and swaps if less than
if (string.Compare(sorter[index], sorter[index + 1]) > 0) 
{
    //swap
    temp = sorter[index];
    sorter[index] = sorter[index + 1];
    sorter[index + 1] = temp;
}
```

Switched to greater than. Should switch the order to the right way.

**Note:** if you were trying to sort the whole array, not just the titles, you should look into making an object for each set of array indexes, then just making them into a `List<Book>` for super easy sorting.

Answer (score 0):

You're only calling `bubbleSort` on `titleArray`, not the other arrays.

Your output is one element from each array, but you haven't sorted the other arrays, so the indexes don't match up any longer.

```
for (arrData = 0; arrData < titleArrayL; arrData++ )
{
    sw.WriteLine("-+-");
    sw.WriteLine(titleArray[arrData]);
    sw.WriteLine(platformArray[arrData]);
    sw.WriteLine(genreArray[arrData]);
    sw.WriteLine(publisherArray[arrData]);
    sw.WriteLine("-+-");
}
```

Rather than four separate arrays, you should store the data in a `List` of objects, and then sort the list. That way the pieces of data will stay together.

To make this work with 4 separate arrays, you need to sort the other arrays - but it's not enough to call `bubbleSort` for each array, you'll need to move their items around to match the changes in `titleArray`.
In other words, `bubbleSort` will have to take **ALL** the arrays, look at `titleArray` but move the corresponding item in all arrays.

That's such a strange way to do things that I would suggest contacting the person who set the problem and asking for clarification.

Comment: I would prefer a 2D array but the excersize in question specifically requests a 1D array for each of the elements, I have a second part of the binary file which has just the sorted TitleArrays, but I think i'm more confused on why my loop doesn't work